# MySQL.EntityFrameworkCore : Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

It's my first post here, so excuse me if there is some informations missing… :)

I’m writing a .NET 7 AspNET API using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore (7.0.2).

I’m facing an issue when I try to update my database using my generated migrations (using dotnet ef)

Here’s the stacktrace is receive :

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
   at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.LoadCharacterSetsAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.ConfigureAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

And here are my entities :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; } = new Guid();
}

public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = default!;

    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class Catalog : BaseAuditableEntity
{
    private List<CatalogItem>? _catalogItems = new();

    public IEnumerable<CatalogItem> CatalogItems =>
        new ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogItem>(_catalogItems!);

    public CatalogVersion Version { get; set; } = CatalogVersion.From(1);

    public CatalogName Name { get; init; } = default!;

    public CatalogKind Kind { get; init; } = default!;

...
}

public class CatalogItem : BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public Guid CatalogId { get; init; }

    public CatalogItemName Name { get; private set; } = default!;

    public CatalogItemType Type { get; private set; } = default!;

    public CatalogItemScope Scope { get; set; }

    public bool Mandatory { get; private set; }

    public string? ValidationString { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? DefaultValue { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

...
}
```

I configured them as follow :

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Catalog> catalogConfiguration)
    {
        catalogConfiguration.OwnsOne(c => c.Name)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();
        ;
        catalogConfiguration.OwnsOne(c => c.Kind)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Kind").IsRequired();
        ;
        catalogConfiguration.OwnsOne(c => c.Version)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Version").IsRequired();
    }

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CatalogItem> catalogItemConfiguration)
    {
        catalogItemConfiguration.OwnsOne(e => e.Name)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();
        catalogItemConfiguration.OwnsOne(e => e.Scope)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Scope").IsRequired();
        catalogItemConfiguration.OwnsOne(e => e.Type)
            .Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Type").IsRequired();
    }
```

I tried to follow some hints by googling the issue but nothing really worked for me.

I tried to pass every property as non-nullable.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error at database update...

I would gladly appreciate some help because I getting a bit lost :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue...

Turns out I was using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore package which is not well maintained.

I switched to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql which is solved my issue.

Comment: Is your database server MariaDB? It looks like you're running into https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109331 where the Oracle MySQL team has said that MariaDB is not supported. Switching to Pomelo (as you've done) will provide compatibility with MariaDB.